# Delphi manipulate state of Dataset

Tags: delphi, dataset

Is there a way to modify the state of my dataset (TTAble) before any delete or edit or insert?

I try to use `Table1.State := dsXXX`. the compiler tell me can't modify this properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this but be careful that, by what you're doing, you aren't subverting the TDataSet's state model.

You need to declare a descendant class of the TDataSet type you are using.  E.g.

```
type TmyTTable = Class(TTable);
```

Then by casting your dataset to that type, you can use `SetTempState` and `RestoreState` on it:

```
SaveState := Table1.State;
try
  TmyTTable(Table1).SetTempState();
  //  do something
finally
  TmyTTable(Table1).RestoreState(SaveState);
end;
```

You should really look at the source of SetTempState in DB.Pas, though.  And proceed with extreme caution - using `SetTempState` is asking for trouble.  SetTempState is used in several places in DBClient.Pas, fwiw.

Answer (score 6):

The property `State` (inherited from class `TDataSet`) is read-only. You are not supposed to manipulate it directly.

To delete/edit/insert a record use the respective methods `Delete`/`Edit`/`Insert`. They change value of `State` as designed.

Presumably (as you don't provide any information on what you are doing or what you have tried), you are asking to modify `State` because you get an error message like

> DataSet not in edit mode.

That's because data manipulation can only be done after the dataset has been opened by calling the `Open` method.

Comment: "data manipulation can only be done after the dataset has been opened"  True, but as a closed dataset is likely to be apparent in the gui, this eoor msg is maybe more likely to arise from omitting to call Edit or Insert.